# Good or Bad, pass parameters using the state of browserHistory

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application

Recently, I started to build a single-page-application using React, and I picked up the react-router to do the navigation part, however when there is a need to pass parameters between pages, I found the solution from the official document was to add the parameters as a query string or parameters in the URL, which is not what I expect (I want to hold the parameters implicit as we do in traditional POST method when communicating with servers).

After a while of googling, I found a solution, call

```
browserHistory.push({
    path : '/Paradise',
    state : { location : 'Shangri-La'}
})
```

to pass the parameter in the state of browserHistory, and retrieve the state using

```
this.props.location.state.location
```

That works fine, and exactly is what I expect. I just want to know if this is a good practice to do so. Sorry for my broken English.

Comment: Your English is absolutely not broken. But until you actually give a reason yourself why you think there is something wrong with this approach, or how it doesn't work for you, this is pretty much an opinionated matter. So far you're questioning something that is in official documentation and works fine. Go explain that to yourself :)

Comment: Agree with @Gimby. What you're doing is absolutely fine. You are using location state the way it's meant to be used. If it is a good practice would depend on your app as a whole. If you only need to send a state between a few pages, then that's fine. If all pages need to do this however, I'd suggest looking into either [tag:react-redux] or [tag:relayjs] with [tag:react-router-relay]. That said, your question is a bit off-topic for this site, and really, not much to say here other than basically a yes/no. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Gimby, for the quick reply. Do you mean by that this is an official approach to manipulate the state as a parameter container, however I didn't find any official documentation from react-router or W3C html5, do you have any reference?

Comment: Thank you @Chris, I will be much more confidence to use it now, and will think about redux if it's needed to pass parameters in a app-wide scope

Answer (score 0):

Good practice is to avoid calling it `location`.. For me,  i call it `previousRoute`.

Another good practice , that i wrap `browserHistory.push` in a method named `redirect` and put in the super class.

```
class Base extends React.Component {

   redirect(to, params  = {} ) {

      params = Object.assign(params, { previousRoute : this.props.location.pathname});
      return browserHistory.push({
        path :  to,
        state : params
      });

   }
}
```

Then :

```
class AnyOtherComponent extends Base {

    //... you can call 
   this.redirect('Paradise', {param1: val1});

}
```